# Where and what is the "cylindrical surface" of wall beneath $z=f(x,y)$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't understand how the surface is "cylindrical" I don't see a cylinder in the attached image. I am wondering what "cylinder" and "surface" they are talking about when they claim "the cylinder cuts through this surface".

A cylinder is the cross product of a disk and some subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The image above that winds and is a wall is not the cross product of a disk and some subset of $\mathbb{R}$. A wall cannot be a cylinder!

Comment: Sometimes, a surface which is parallel to some line is called a cylindrical surface. I believe that is the case here.

Comment: What is the "line" that this "surface is parallel to?

Comment: Well, first when I say "parallel," I am talking about rulings of a surface. In this case, the rulings are parallel to the $z$-axis.

Comment: but the rulings $\neq$ surface

Comment: Rulings are lines which pass through a surface. Here is a definition from Early Transcendentals (Stewart):

"A cylinder is a surface that consists of all lines (called rulings) that are parallel to a given line and pass through a given plane curve."

Comment: So every manifold or surface is a "cylinder"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69641/discussion-between-cws-and-cake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general context, a “cylindrical surface” is a surface formed by the motion of a line (the generator) moving parallel to itself and intersecting a given curve (the directrix).

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cylindrical_surface_(cylinder)